# What is The Prediction as defined by the Mahayana tradition?

Tags: reference-request, mahayana, sutras

Please see this section taken from the wiki page titled [Boddhisattva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhisattva) which might help you answer the question:

> ...what early Mahayana sutras like the Aṣṭa do is to help individuals
> determine if they have already received **a prediction** in a past life,
> or if they are close to this point. The Aṣṭa provides a variety of
> methods, including forms of ritual or divination, methods dealing with
> dreams and various tests, especially tests based on one's reaction to
> the hearing of the content in the Aṣṭasāhasrikā itself. The text
> states that encountering and accepting its teachings mean one is close
> to being given **a prediction** and that if one does not "shrink back,
> cower or despair" from the text, but "firmly believes it", one is
> irreversible. Many other Mahayana sutras such as the Akṣobhyavyūha and
> the Śūraṃgamasamādhi Sūtra present textual approaches to determine
> one's status as an advanced bodhisattva. These mainly consist in one's
> attitude towards listening to, believing, preaching, proclaiming,
> copying or memorizing and reciting the sutra. According to Drewes,
> this claim that merely having faith in Mahāyāna sūtras meant that one
> was an advanced bodhisattva, was a departure from previous Nikaya
> views about bodhisattvas. It created new groups of Buddhists who
> accepted each other's bodhisattva status.

Also, is the Śūraṃgamasamādhi Sūtra the same as Leng Yen Ching? And, is there an English translation of the Akṣobhyavyūha sutra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "prediction" is a statement made by an enlightened person, originally a previous Buddha, or, in Mahayana tradition, an enlightened master, that guarantees its object eventual attainment of enlightenment in a subsequent existence.

Comment: Is this similar to reaching stream entry in the Theravada tradition?

Comment: Yup, I think it is conceptually very similar. Not sure if it signifies exactly same level of insight or something higher or lower as stream entry, but it does mark a milestone in one's realization yes.